# Inline comments for ConfigParser

Tags: python, comments, ini, configparser

I have stuff like this in an .ini file

```
[General]
verbosity = 3   ; inline comment

[Valid Area Codes]
; Input records will be checked to make sure they begin with one of the area 
; codes listed below.  

02    ; Central East New South Wales & Australian Capital Territory
03    ; South East Victoria & Tasmania
;04    ; Mobile Telephones Australia-wide
07    ; North East Queensland
08    ; Central & West Western Australia, South Australia & Northern Territory
```

However I have the problem that inline comments are working in the `key = value` line, but not in the `key` with no value lines.  Here is how I am creating my ConfigParser object:

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> c = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
>>> c.read('example.ini')
['example.ini']
>>> c.get('General', 'verbosity')
'3'
>>> c.options('General')
['verbosity']
>>> c.options('Valid Area Codes')
['02    ; central east new south wales & australian capital territory', '03    ; south east victoria & tasmania', '07    ; north east queensland', '08    ; central & west western australia, south australia & northern territory']
```

How can I setup the config parser so that inline comments work for both cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the ConfigParser documentation

"Configuration files may include comments, prefixed by specific characters (# and ;). Comments may appear on their own in an otherwise empty line, or **may be entered in lines holding values or section names**"

**In your case you are adding comments in lines holding just keys without values (hence it will not work) , and that's why you are getting that output.**

REFER:
http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#safeconfigparser-objects

Comment: I agree, I looked up the ConfigParser code as well. There is no way that it can be customized. First I thought that it was a bug in the config parser code itself, but then I went back and read the doc carefully and saw that they have specified it explicitly.

Comment: The current Python 3.5.2 ConfigParser documentation mentions a customization capability for this.  

[You can use comments] 
# like this
; or this

# By default only in an empty line.
# Inline comments can be harmful because they prevent users
# from using the delimiting characters as parts of values.
# That being said, this can be customized.

Answer (score 10):

[EDIT]

Modern ConfigParser supports in-line comments.

```
settings_cfg = configparser.ConfigParser(inline_comment_prefixes="#")
```

However, if you want to waste a function declaration for supported methods, here's my original post:

---

[ORIGINAL]

As SpliFF stated, the documentation says in-line comments are a no-no. Everything right of the first colon or equal sign is passed as the value, including comment delimiters.

Which sucks.

So, let's fix that:

```
def removeInlineComments(cfgparser):
    for section in cfgparser.sections():
        for item in cfgparser.items(section):
            cfgparser.set(section, item[0], item[1].split("#")[0].strip())
```

The above function goes through every item in every section of a configParser object, splits the string on any '#' symbol, then strip()'s any white space from the leading or trailing edges of the remaining value, and writes back just the value, free of inline comments.

Here's a more pythonic, (if arguably less legible) list comprehension version of this function, that allows you to specifiy what character to split on:

```
def removeInlineComments(cfgparser, delimiter):
    for section in cfgparser.sections():
        [cfgparser.set(section, item[0], item[1].split(delimiter)[0].strip()) for item in cfgparser.items(section)]
```

Comment: settings_cfg = configparser.ConfigParser(inline_comment_prefixes="#") is just not working for me... I am using configparser-5.2.0 with Python 3
edit: it still prints the #comment when i try to print the value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `02= ; comment` instead.

Comment: It doesn't really work properly, it puts the "; comment" in as the value.